# SQL Server generic trigger creation

Tags: sql-server, triggers, ntext

I am trying to create a generic trigger in SQL Server which can copy all column data from Table A and insert them in corresponding fields in Table B.

There are few problems I am facing.

I need this copy to occur under three conditions : `INSERT`, `DELETE` and `UPDATE`.

1. The trigger needs to be triggered after CUD operations. using AFTER throws SQL error saying `ntext` etc are not supported in inserted. How do I resolve this error?
2. Instead of if used can work for `INSERT` but not for delete. Is there a way to do this for delete operations?
3. Is there a way I can write a generic code inside the trigger which can work for all sorts of tables (we can assume that all the columns in table a exists in column b)

I am not well versed with triggers or for that matter DDL in SQL Server.

Appreciate if some can provide me some solutions.

Thanks
Ben

Answer (score 0):

[CREATE TRIGGER (Transact-SQL)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189799%28v=sql.105%29.aspx)

1. Use `nvarchar(max)` instead of `ntext`.
2. You can have an `instead of` trigger for delete.
3. You can have one trigger that handles insert/update/delete for one table but you can not connect a trigger to more than one table.